# App crashes on start of new activity (Using Accelerometer data)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi was trying to implement [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/) (my activity called main) as an activity into my app, which could be launched by pressing a button from the MainPage java class, but every time I hit the button to launch the activity it crashes, I think it might have something to do with requesting permissions to use accelerometer data, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help

here's the MainPage which the activity I'm having trouble with is launched from:

```java
package shake.shake;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Button ShakeButton1;
    private static ImageButton SettingsButton1;
    private static ImageButton HistoryButton1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }
    public void OnClickButtonListener()
    {
        ShakeButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ShakeButton);
        ShakeButton1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intentSecondActivity = new Intent(MainPage.this, main.class);
                        startActivity(intentSecondActivity);
                            }
                });
        SettingsButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.SettingsButton);
        SettingsButton1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intentSecondActivity = new Intent(MainPage.this, Settingspage.class);
                        startActivity(intentSecondActivity);
                    }
                });
        HistoryButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.HistoryButton);
        HistoryButton1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intentSecondActivity = new Intent(MainPage.this, Historypage.class);
                        startActivity(intentSecondActivity);
                    }
                });
}}
```

Here's the activity that crashes the app:

```java
package shake.shake;

/**
 * Created by ink on 3/24/16.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private float mLastX, mLastY, mLastZ;
    private boolean mInitialized;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private final float NOISE = (float) 2.0;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mInitialized = false;
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
// can be safely ignored for this demo
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        TextView tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
        TextView tvY= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
        TextView tvZ= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.z_axis);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        if (!mInitialized) {
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            tvX.setText("0.0");
            tvY.setText("0.0");
            tvZ.setText("0.0");
            mInitialized = true;
        }
        else {
            float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
            float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);
            if (deltaX < NOISE) deltaX = (float)0.0;
            if (deltaY < NOISE) deltaY = (float)0.0;
            if (deltaZ < NOISE) deltaZ = (float)0.0;
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            tvX.setText(Float.toString(deltaX));
            tvY.setText(Float.toString(deltaY));
            tvZ.setText(Float.toString(deltaZ));
            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (deltaX > deltaY) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.horizontal);
            } else if (deltaY > deltaX) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.vertical);
            } else {
                iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also here's the manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="shake.shake">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainPage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settingspage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settingspage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Historypage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_historypage"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here's the crashlog:

```html
03-27 21:55:40.742 19759-19759/shake.shake E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: shake.shake, PID: 19759
                                                             android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {shake.shake/shake.shake.main}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:843)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
                                                                 at shake.shake.MainPage$1.onClick(MainPage.java:29)
                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21155)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: did you add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />` to the manifest  , strictly this isn't required but I'm not fammiliar with what has changed recently?

Comment: Did you check your code against the source code (available on the link you provided)? Also you don't need special permission to access this particular sensor.

Comment: just added it still crashing... :/

Comment: Look at this line
`Intent intentSecondActivity = new Intent(MainPage.this, main.class);`. This implies that when this widget is interacted with, the class "main" needs to be launched from the "MainPage" activity. you don't have a class called "main" in your project. you just have MainPage, , which I presume is not what you want to launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add manifest about your "main" class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="shake.shake">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainPage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".main" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Settingspage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settingspage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Historypage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_historypage"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```